# iPhone: Is Quartz 2D the only way to generate PDF files?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, pdf, quartz-graphics

I can't convert an HTML file for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quartz 2D is the only method I've found. [Opacity](http://likethought.com/opacity/) can generate source code allowing visual design/layout of the PDF templates.